# how can i pass 2 arrays as datas in googlechart

Tags: php, google-visualization

I'm using *google charts easy php class* ([here's the link of it](http://code.google.com/p/googlechartseasyphpclass/))
and i want to draw Multiple Vertical Bar Chart,
as the documentation says "Separate multiple data sets with |"
so i try this , but nothing happens

```
 $chart1=new googleChart($a | $b ,'bary' );
```

*note that both $a & $b are arrays

i would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

try `$chart1=new googleChart(implode(',', $a).'|'.implode(',',$b) ,'bary' );`

or
see "CHART WITH 3 DIFFERENT DATA SETS" here http://code.google.com/p/googlechartseasyphpclass/wiki/Documentation
where it creates an array with all your data arrays and then passes it to the Google Chart object with the `smartDataLabel` function